# Put every character in a sentence into a vector?

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I started coding a couple months ago and I can't figure out how to work out this problem. Here is what is asked..

1. Ask the user to type a phrase. Remove all the spaces from the phrase and turn all letters to upper case.
2. Create a vector to store every letters of the phrase into one position, the vector must be the exact same size of the phrase.
3. Show the content of the vector on screen.

I hit a wall were I can't start with a vector because of the remove spaces and upper case of item 1 but if I start with a normal String I don't know how to split letters by letters as asked in item 2.

```
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a phrase.");
    String phrase = entrada.nextLine();
    phrase = phrase.replace(" ", "");
    phrase = phrase.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(phrase);
    int characters = phrase.length();
    System.out.println("The phrase has" + characters + "characters");
    String[] vet = new String[characters];
    for (int i = 0; i < characters; i++) {
```

Comment: See [String.charAt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))

Comment: What do you mean by this: _store every letters of the phrase into one position_ ?  Why do you need to use obsolete `Vector` class, should it be a list/arraylist?

Comment: @AlexRudenko i guess the 'vector' is not the Vector class but its the 'vector' phrase. So, an array is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`phrase.toCharArray()` should do the trick.

In case you want the characters to be stored in a list:

```
List<Character> list = phrase.chars()
    .mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: phrase.toCharArray() worked, thank you mate

Answer (score 0):

Your teaching materials sound a little out of date. @user16632363 is right about how to access each `char`. Having done `List<Character> allCharacters = new ArrayList<>();` earlier. you can now do:

```
int numChars = phrase.length();
for(int i = 0;i < numChars;i++) {  
   allChars.add(Character.valueOf(phrase.charAt(i)));
}
```